# Stimulate recipients login mail exchange server?

Tags: exchange-server

I have the mail exchange server for pratice. And in this exchange server, I create a bulk recipients but still not logon anytime.

When I run Get-MailboxStatics it return an warning that:

> WARNING: The user hasn't logged on to mailbox 'abc'
>   ('76768175-4db5-4cbb-a36b-fdbde574ccbc'), so there is no data to
>   return. After the user logs on, this warning will no longer appear.

So with the large number recipients over 100, how can I use powershell code to stimulate that I already logon successful for all recipient in this server?

Comment: I remember sending a mail to the new mailboxes has the same effect. What matters that the mailbox has to get initialized, by user login or by receiving a first message.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at using LoadGen https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40726 and that will generate load on the server which will populate all the log files for you to look at and test. (the 2013 version will run fine on Exchange 2016).